# Call a function from one module to another module

Tags: angularjs

I have two angularjs file. I have created some function inside a controller.Now I want to call this function from another module and controller.I tried by injecting the module dependency into my caller module .But it is not recognizing the function.I am new in angularjs.

This is the module I want to call

```
var app = angular.module("demo", []);
        app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope,$http,$window) {
           $scope.temp = "";
           $scope.rows = []; // init empty array
           $scope.datainput =[];
           $scope.dataconfig =[];

            $scope.myrunner=function(canvasid,inputdata,configdata){

                var flag=0;
                $scope.datainput=inputdata;
                $scope.dataconfig=configdata;
                console.log("from base module");                
            }

            $scope.refresh = function(){
                location.reload();              
            }
        });
```

This is the caller module

```
var app = angular.module("tester", ["demo"]);
    app.controller("mycontroller", function($scope) {


        var input=[{"status":"PAY_FAIL","value":6248},{"status":"PAY_SUCCESS","value":868},{"status":"PM_REQUESTED","value":11199},{"status":"PAY_INIT","value":992}] ;


        var config=[
        {"type":"font_name","value":"Calibri"},
        {"type":"font_size","value":"25px"}
        ] ;


        $scope.myfn=function(){



            demo.myrunner('myCanvas',input,config);
            demo.myrunner('myCanvas2',input,config);
        }


        $scope.myfn();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the factory to communicate between two modules. You cannot have the function inside a controller and call the function from another module.

Example:

```
var moduleA= angular.module('demo',[]);
moduleA.factory('factoryA', function() {
    return {
        alertA: function() {
            alert('a');
        }    
    };
});
```

Then use the alertA factory in module B:

```
angular.module('tester',['A']).controller('mycontroller',function($scope,'factoryA'){
    factoryA.alertA();
});
```

Comment: Thank you  very much.I am trying your approach.

Comment: Of course @Sajeetharan

Comment: ```angular.module("tester", ["demo"]).controller("mycontroller", function($scope,'factoryA') {``` In this line I am getting unexpected string error

Comment: what is the error

Comment: ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string``` This is the error

Comment: In the controller parameter 'functionA' will be passed as value not as string.@Sajee